# I tried oneplus 8 pro with ubuntu: no lsusb/adb output

Tags: usb-debugging, android-sdk, android-11

I have oneplus 8 pro connected to my ubuntu 20.04 box and installed:

- vendor driver
- android sdk
- adb/fastboot

But different USB cables show no output in

- `lsusb`
- `adb devices`
- `fastboot devices`

I have already reset usb-debugging and according authorization! I faintly remember having struggled with debugging authentication before...

What can I try next?

Comment: No, not at all: I have stock Android 11 from oneplus called `Oxygen OS`. I just want to use `adb` from the remote computer!

Comment: Sorry I was confused by the title. In my interpretation of the title you claim you have installed Ubuntu on your oneplus 8. When the device does not show up in `lsusb` then the other commands also will fail. Try to connect the phone to a different PC and check if it is detected there. If not the USB port of your device may be damaged. Does the phone charge normally?

Comment: No problem! I attached the smartphone to windows `adb` works fine... Ubuntu is my primary development machine: charging of the smartphone works but there is no usb debug authentication. I think I will have to wait for bugfix updates!